# Transferring focus from one form popup to another in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, focus

Working in Access 2010

I have a search form, that causes a report to pup up, that causes a item detail report to pop up.

All 3 forms are set side by side.

The problem is, I cannot simply click on one of these windows to go back to clicking buttons in it. If I want to navigate back to the results report, I have to exit out of the detail report, and if I want to go back to the Search form, I have to exit out of the Results report.

How can I add a way to jump focus to and from these windows without having to click out of the most recently oppened one?

Comment: I didnt use any code. Instead I made a button and set OnCLick to OpenForm search_form.

Comment: It still doesnt work. I cant click on anything outside of the search form window until I click out of the search form.

Comment: Are your popups set to be `Modal` as well?

Comment: Yes. This is very frustrating and the last part I need to figure out to complete this project.

Answer (score 0):

`Modal` means that when that form is opened *Only* that form can have focus. All other forms will have to wait until your most recently opened modal form is closed before it will relinquish focus.

Usually you will use this when you need a form's input before you can continue working on the parent form that called it. In your case it seems like you have a bunch of forms that are all supposed to be used simultaneously, in which case you do not want them to be modal. Set it to `No`